# Retrieve wikidata related data entities from wikipedia

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, wikidata

I used this request to retrieve soccer players and some of their properties (name, team, team number, apperances, goals) since the last two years:

```
SELECT ?SoccerPlayer ?SoccerPlayerLabel ?Team ?TeamLabel ?TeamNumber ?numMatches ?numGoals ?startTime WHERE {?SoccerPlayer wdt:P106 wd:Q937857; p:P54 ?stmt . ?stmt ps:P54 ?Team; pq:P1350 ?numMatches; pq:P1351 ?numGoals; pq:P580 ?startTime . optional {?stmt pq:P1618 ?TeamNumber} filter not exists {?SoccerPlayer p:P54/pq:P580 ?startTimeOther filter(?startTimeOther > ?startTime)} #FILTER(?startTime >= "2018-01-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime). SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".} } limit 200
```

I want to retrieve the corresponding entites from wikipedia with the same properties

Comment: with exactly the same properties? Just repeat the triple pattern but use a different var for the player. Just as a sketch: `SELECT ?SoccerPlayer ?numGoals WHERE {?SoccerPlayer wdt:numGoals ?numGoals . ?SoccerPlayerOther wdt:numGoals ?numGoals .  filter(?SoccerPlayer != ?SoccerPlayerOther)}` - just do it for all properties. But I doubt you'll find anything with exactly all those properties. I mean, same team, same number of goals, same matches? Would be weird, right?

Comment: @AKSW should I use the mediaWiki Api or there is an endpoint to query wikipedia?

Comment: I misread the question, here for Wikipedia pages a sketch query: `select ?SoccerPlayer ?article {
  ?SoccerPlayer wdt:P106 wd:Q937857 .
  OPTIONAL {
      ?article schema:about ?SoccerPlayer .
      ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/> .
  }
  } limit 100` - you have to add it to your query then